# Is there a built-in (no for loop) way to put ranges of a vector into a cell array using a matrix for the indices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array, matrix-indexing

Given:

```
data = 0:10;
indices = [1 2; 3 7; 2 5];
```

Is there a one-line way to do this?:

```
for i = 1:length(indices)
    out{i} = data(indices(i,1):indices(i,2))
end
```

Comment: An extra tip: as per [this Documentation page](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/973/common-mistakes-and-errors/27689/using-length-for-multidimensional-arrays#t=201703292057296513663), you want to be using the `size` function instead of the `length` function.

Comment: Agreed - I recently got bit by that, but haven't changed my habit yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html):

```
out = arrayfun(@(a,b) data(a:b), indices(:,1), indices(:,2), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

However, internally `arrayfun` is still probably just using a for loop, so I wouldn't expect to see any improvement in speed. This syntax simply allows you to write it as a one-liner. A somewhat ugly one-liner.

Comment: I kind-of figured it wouldn't be as neat as I hoped.  And I definitely didn't expect a performance improvement.  But this taught me a new tool, which is valuable.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following is on

```
out = arrayfun(@(ii)data(indices(ii,1):indices(ii,2)),1:size(indices,1),'UniformOutput',false)
```